# getResourceAsStream returning null after it had worked

Tags: java, resources

I am running an application from a servlet container. This application produces letters which are derived from some file templates that packed with the jar. I get hold of these files by `Class.getResourceAsStrem` and the application works perfectly fine.

However, after thousands of invocations, the method suddently returns `null` and continues to return `null` until the application is restarted. I have no explanation for this and I cannot see a reason why this would suddenly happen.

I first thought this might be because of unclosed streams pointing to the same resource but I am wrapping the stream processing in a `catch`-`try`-block right after opening it. Also, a heap dump does not show such stream objects and I furthermore think that this should result in an `IOException` instead. Also, it says in the javadoc

> A InputStream object or null if no resource with this name is found

But why would the application suddenly not longer be able to find a resource it successfully found before.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are these files?

Comment: In a sub folder of the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the reason. `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String)` to which `Class.getResourceAsStream` eventually delegates is implemented like this:

```
public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
    URL url = getResource(name);
    try {
        return url != null ? url.openStream() : null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I guess there is an `IOException` occurring and that there are indeed leaking open files. However, this exception gets swallowed and I get a `null` pointer in return. Genius API...

**Update**: After looking at a heap dump, I found application code that was leaking files. Damn you, `ClassLoader` implementation, misdirecting me with `NullPointerException`s.

Comment: `After looking at a heap dump..` - how you got it?

Comment: I found instances of `OutputStream` lying on the heap that were not closed but should have been. (Using JVisualVM: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) I traced these instances and found that one stream was closed twice while another one was never closed. Typical copy-paste, I assume.