# Class.getResource() returns null after a long time running

Tags: java

I'm using `Class.getResource()` to load a file from the jar of a long-running Java app. It works fine. But after the app has been running for a long time, it starts returning `null`.

How do I troubleshoot this? All I can see are exceptions caused by `getResource()` returning `null`; but I can't find out *why* it's returning `null`.

I have checked for unclosed streams returned by `Class.getResourceAsStream()`, but I'm not calling that. (Although, one of my libraries might...) I have also checked for FileInputStreams that aren't being closed, but I haven't found any. (FileInputStreams continue to be usable while this is happening.)

Edit: this appears to be the same issue as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252261/getresourceasstream-returning-null-after-it-had-worked?). Also, [possibly related](http://www.genevski.com/2010/04/javaneturl-and-jarurlconnection-may.html).

Comment: I'd start by decompiling the classes in question, calling the same methods they do, and logging the results. For a start, I'd log `Class.getClassLoader0()`, `Class.getClassLoader0().getResource()`, `Class.getClassLoader0().getParent().getResource()`, `Class.getClassLoader0().getBootstrapResource()` and `Class.getClassLoader0().findResource()` (most of which are accessible only by reflection) - and of course compare their outputs before and after `.getResource()` stops working.

Comment: @Siguza Thank you! I will try that, and report back in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I had code that was reading the version out of MANIFEST.MF from an InputStream returned by `URL.openStream()`:

```
String manifestPath = classPath.substring(0, webInfIndex) +
        "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";

// DON'T DO THIS!!!
// openStream() returns an InputStream that never gets closed.
Manifest manifest = new Manifest(new URL(manifestPath).openStream());
Attributes attr = manifest.getMainAttributes();
String version = attr.getValue(Attributes.Name.IMPLEMENTATION_VERSION);
```

Fixing the leak using Java 7 try-with-resources:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = new URL(manifestPath).openStream()) {
    Manifest manifest = new Manifest(inputStream);
    Attributes attr = manifest.getMainAttributes();
    String version = attr.getValue(Attributes.Name.IMPLEMENTATION_VERSION);
}
```